# Ember 2.4 - get current user using a service and simple auth after login

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have the following problem with getting the current user using an instance initializer, a service and ember-simple-auth library. 
More specifically, I have managed to get all the attributes of my service "user" but only when I refresh the page after login. 
I would like the promise that my service returns to be immediately accessible right after login.
My code snippets are available below:

*app/instance-initializers/current-user.js*

```
export function initialize(appInstance) {

    appInstance.inject('route', 'account', 'service:account');
    appInstance.inject('controller', 'account', 'service:account');
    appInstance.inject('template', 'account', 'service:account');
}

export default {
    name: 'account',
    initialize: initialize
};
```

*app/services/account.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({

session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
store: Ember.inject.service('store'),

loadCurrentUser() {

    const accountId = this.get('session.data.authenticated.auth_token');
    console.log("This is my account", accountId);

    if (!Ember.isEmpty(accountId)) {

        this.get('store').findRecord('profile',  accountId).then((profile) => {
            this.set('user', profile);
            console.log("account_group",this.get('user.user_group'));
            console.log("account_username",this.get('user.username'));
        }); 
    }
    return this.get('user')              
}
});
```

Then I call the loadCurrentUser function in my application route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin,{

    beforeModel(){
    console.log("This is my currentUser",   this.get("account").loadCurrentUser());
},

});
```

And finally in my template I can access the username of my user like this:

```
Logged in as: {{account.user.username}}
```

but only when I refresh my page.

I assume that I call my function "loadCurrentUser()" in the wrong place but I can't find anywhere a proper solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should call `loadCurrentUser()` when the authenticator resolves the promise. Something like:

```
that.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:xxxx',{}).then(() => { 
    this.get("account").loadCurrentUser();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It worked fine after the user's login but I have to keep my code in the application.js route in order to work when I refresh the page. I would be more than grateful If you could provide a hint about that.

Comment: As a first thought, I would place the code also in the application route for page refresh as you did `beforeModel() { this.get("account").loadCurrentUser(); }` or add a `init` method in the service `init() { this._super(...arguments); this.loadCurrentUser(); }` (don't forget the call to `_super()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, your comment was really valuable!